# How to invert mouse cursor behaviour in Mouse Area

Tags: qt, qml

I want to invert direction of mouse cursor. For example when I move mouse right - cursor move to left, when I move mouse up - cursor move to down. And I want do it if mouse on pressed left button.

Comment: If you want to reverse the result coordinate, do this `width - x, height - y` otherwise it's not possible to reverse mouse movement on the QML side, but maybe on the OS level.

Comment: what is your real goal? why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the real cursor and place a fake cursor in a different position. In the following example:

- A define a `Rectangle` where the reverse mouse area applies
- `MouseArea` requires `containsMouse` and `pressed` before `reverse` mode is actived
- `MouseArea` hides the real mouse with `Qt.BlankCursor`
- Will display a fake mouse using an SVG recreation of the mouse cursor
- When the reverse mode is enabled we flip the coordinates of the fake mouse with `parent.width - mouseArea.mouseX` and `parent.height - mouseArea.mouseY`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "#ffe"
        border.color: "grey"
        width: Math.floor(parent.width / 2)
        height: Math.floor(parent.height / 2)

        Image {
             id: fakeMouse
             x: mouseArea.reversed
                     ? parent.width - mouseArea.mouseX
                     : mouseArea.mouseX
             y: mouseArea.reversed
                     ? parent.height - mouseArea.mouseY
                     : mouseArea.mouseY
             visible: mouseArea.containsMouse
             source: "cursor-32.svg"
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            property bool reversed: pressed & containsMouse
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            cursorShape: Qt.BlankCursor
        }

        Frame {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.margins: 10
            visible: fakeMouse.visible
            Label {
                 text: fakeMouse.x + " " + fakeMouse.y
            }
        }
    }
}

//cursor-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M9 25.282l4.3-5.894 4.062 8.043 5.016-2.523L18.416 17h7.01L9 5.016zm.99-18.318l12.398 9.046h-5.575l4.237 8.457-3.25 1.635-4.346-8.606-3.464 4.749z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)